# I cannot activate virtualenv on windows 10

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am trying to activate virtualenv on windows 10x64 by using this command:

```
source \env\Scripts\activate.bat
```

but I get this error:

```
source : The term 'source' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, 
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that 
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ source \env\Scripts\activate.bat
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (source:String) [], CommandNotFoundException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: just run the command `env\Scripts\activate.bat`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok about that, source is a shell command that only used in Linux systems, but not for windows systems.
In window you should run it as...(Let's assume directory is inside of C:)

```
C:\Users\env\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Windows 10 too. Unfortunately, `source` can only be used on Linux-based systems. After several rabbit holes searching, I was able to solve it. Assuming your directory appears like this:

```
C:\Users\Workspace>
```

Just type in front of that:

```
C:\Users\Workspace> .\virt_env\Scripts\activate
```

Assuming `virt_env` is the name of your virtual environment.