# How to activate virtualenv on Windows?

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I removed the virtualenv first and then create it again. By running `.\\Envs\automation_cookbook\Scripts\activate.bat` as it is mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099720/i-cannot-activate-virtualenv-on-windows-10). But the prompt doesn't change at all. I doubt if I'm running it successfully.

```
PS C:\Users\yashi> rmvirtualenv automation_cookbook

    Deleted C:\Users\yashi\Envs\automation_cookbook

PS C:\Users\yashi> mkvirtualenv automation_cookbook
created virtual environment CPython3.9.0.final.0-64 in 329ms
  creator CPython3Windows(dest=C:\Users\yashi\Envs\automation_cookbook, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\yashi\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.3.1, setuptools==51.0.0, wheel==0.36.1
  activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
PS C:\Users\yashi> .\\Envs\automation_cookbook\Scripts\activate.bat
PS C:\Users\yashi> 
PS C:\Users\yashi> lsvirtualenv

dir /b /ad "C:\Users\yashi\Envs"
==============================================================================
automation_cookbook
```

Edit: I was trying it via virtualenvwrappe

Comment: Probably you figured it out by now ; but for those who come looking like I did ... Your prompt is PowerShell, so you need to activate `YourVenv\Scripts\activate.ps1` not `.bat`

Answer (score 8):

To make a virtual-environment : `python -m venv <env-name>`

To activate : `Scripts/activate.bat`

To deactivate: `Scripts/deactivate.bat`

To delete : simply delete the folder

Comment: Sorry, I didn't state the question clear. I was trying it via virtualenvwrapper

Comment: is `venv` even a python script?

Answer (score 2):

1. To create a virtual environment on windows use python -m venv <env_name>
2. To activate a virtual environment on windows use **.\env_name\Scripts\activate.bat** **Please note the slashes on windows.
3. To de-activate a virtual environment on windows use **.\env_name\Scripts\deactivate.bat** **Please note the slashes

Answer (score 1):

If you made a virtual environment using `python -m venv <env-name>` and you are using PowerShell

Then from the same folder, `./<env-name>/Scripts/activate.bat` will activate it

and `./<env-name>/Scripts/deactivate.bat` will deactivate it.

There will also be `./<env-name>/Scripts/Activate.ps1`, but no matching `Deactivate.ps1`